# LC filter, frequency limit?

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, passive-networks, bandwidth

Do practical implementations of LC filters have a limited bandwidth over which they operate? ie. Would they start to attenuate less as the frequency of the input signal get very high (MHz->GHz)?

Comment: There is a distance vs wavelength thing to watch out for above a GHz.

Comment: There are also parasitics that turn inductors into capacitors, and vice versa.